# login page keeps looping

Tags: php, html, session

when i click on the login link after logged in, it required to login again. 
The session was save 
i insert header to redirect to other page if i click on the login page after logged but still the same.

here is my login process php

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.save_path",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "../../sessionData");
    session_start();


    include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Login Process</title></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test1.css">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
<body>
    <div id="title">

             <p><h1>Tyne Events</h1></p>

        </div>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="navbar" > 
                <ul class="nav">
                     <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="findoutmore.php">Find out more</a></li>
                     <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
                     <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
                     <li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
                     <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                     <li> 
                        <form class="formright">
                        <input  type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button  type="submit">Search</button>                                          
                        </form> 
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>  

            <div id= "content">

<?php
$username   = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'userName') ? $_POST['userName']: null;
$passWD     = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,      'pwd') ? $_POST['pwd']     : null;
$username   = trim($username);
$passWD     = trim($passWD);


    $errorList = array();//create an empty array

    if (empty($username)){
        $errorList[]="<p> You have not enterd Username</p>\n";
    }

    if (empty($passWD)){
    $errorList[]="<p>You have no enter password</p>\n" ;
    }

    if(!empty($errorList))
    {
        echo "<p><em>The following problem(s):</em></p>\n";
        for ($a=0; $a < count($errorList); $a++) 
         echo "$errorList[$a] \n";      
    }

    else{


    /* Query the users database table to get the password hash for the username entered by the user in the logon form */
    $sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM te_users WHERE username = ?";

    // prepare the sql statement
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);      

    /* Bind the $username entered by the user to the prepared statement. Note the “s” part indicates the data type used – in this case a string */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

    // execute the query            
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

    /* Get the password hash from the query results for the given username and store it in the variable indicated */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash);

    /* Check if a record was returned by the query. If yes, then there was a username matching what was entered in the logon form and 
    we can now test to see if the password entered in the logon form is the same as the stored (correct) one in the database. */
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

     $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;

    // password was correct
    if(password_verify($passWD , $passWDHash)){
     $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
     echo "<p>password correct</p>\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "Password incorrect.";
    }

    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] == true) 
        {
            echo "<p>".$_SESSION['uName']."</p>\n";
            echo "<p><a href=\"#\">Admin Link </a>\n";
            echo "<p><a href=\"logout.php\"> Log out here </a></p>";
        }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my login page which i use if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] == true)  to check logged-in.

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.save_path",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "../../sessionData");
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] == true) 
    {
        header(' Location :admin.php');
    }

    include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test1.css">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="title">

         <p><h1>Tyne Events</h1></p>

    </div>


<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navbar" > 
            <ul class="nav">
                 <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="findoutmore.php">Find out more</a></li>
                 <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
                 <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
                 <li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
                 <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                 <li> 
                    <form class="formright">
                    <input  type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    <button  type="submit">Search</button>                                          
                    </form> 
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>  

    <div id= "content">

        <div id="login">

            <form method = "post" action="logonProcess.php">

            <fieldset>
            <legend>LOGIN</legend>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>User Name </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userName"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td> 45$Qr87$482d
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Logon">
            </fieldset>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is page name of the second block

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` or `print_r($_SESSION)` to see what you get.

Comment: login.php second page